# How to render a graph when Mysql data is updated in Vue?

Tags: mysql, node.js, vue.js, graph

I organized like this,

**Back-end**: Nodejs - Insert a data to MYSQL periodically.

**DB**: MYSQL

### **Front-end**: Vue.js - Draw and Re-render a Graph with Mysql Data when data is updated.

In this situation, do I have to check a MYSQL data per seconds whether it is latest or not? and then I have to render a graph again?

Or is there a way like when MYSQL data is updated, triggering a specific methods that is re-render a graph(automatically).

I prefer a second way though, I have no idea it is possible.
Someone can give an advises me plz? or example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is using socket.io for this. The moment you update your database in Node.js you then also send a notification or the data over a socket, which tells your Vue.js application that it needs to load new data or gives it the data directly.

I used the following npm packages for my setup with Vue.js and Node.js:

```
 Vue: socket.io-client  
 Node: socket.io
```

I followed these 2 sites when I faced a similar problem to get a hang of sockets:
https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#Introduction
https://medium.com/@jaouad_45834/basic-chat-web-app-using-express-js-vue-js-socket-io-429588e841f0